# MATLAB loop function issue

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm trying to simplify some calculations for a project i'm working on. I have to calculate the normal stress, strain and displacement and shear stress, strain for three models with three different pore areas and three material types. In total i should have 9 values for each parameter i'm calculating.

I keep getting error on the * for AoP, also when I check the calculation for AoP, it only show the pi value and ignores that it should be the first p^2 value times pi times 25.

This is my code below:

```
% Height[m]
h= 0.0045;
%Length o[m]
l=0.0025;
%cross-sectional area [m]
a=h*l;
%Force [N]
f=1000;   
% three pores [m]
p=[0.00150 0.00175 0.00200]
% three materials E used 
E=[ 1.138e12 6.96e10 1.25e-3]
% three materials G used
G=[ 4.20e10 2.630e10 2.4e10]
AoP=25*(pi()*(p)^2)
for p=1:3 E=1:3 G=1:3
    AoP=25*(pi()*(p)^2) 
    A=a-AoP
    %Normal Stress 
    NSTRESS =f/A
    %Normal Strain
    NSTRAIN = NSTRESS/E
    %Normal Displacement 
    NormalDisplacment = NSTRAIN*h
    %Shear stress
    SStress=f/a
    %Shear strain 
    SStrain=SStress/G
    %Shear displacement
    SDisplacement =  SStrain*h
end

disp (NSTRESS)
disp (NSTRAIN)
disp (NormalDisplacment)
disp (SStress)
disp (SStrain)
disp (SDisplacement)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is resetting p (and E and G) to 1, 2, and 3, and you should only loop through one thing at a time.  You need to use an integer as a loop iterator, then use that integer as a subscript of p:

```
for ip = 1: 3
    for iE = 1: 3
        for iG = 1: 3
            AoP=25*(pi*p(ip)^2) 
        end
    end
end
```

Every time you want to use `p` or `E` or `G` in a calculation, you need to give them their respective subscripts:

```
p(ip)
E(iE)
G(iG)
```

The parentheses `()` after pi don't hurt, but they're unnecessary.  The `disp` statements at the end are also unnecessary, because they will be displayed inside the loop.